# I have an error in my basic R code? missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

Basically I'm trying to remove some elements from my vector in R, but i keep getting this error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
Here is the code:

```
exA2b = function(x){
  m=mean(x)
  s=sd(x)
  print(x)
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  {
    if(x[i]<=m-2*s|x[i]>=m+2*s)
    {
      x=x[-i]
    }
  }
  print(x)
}
x=scan("test.txt")
exA2b(x)
```

and here is the text file:

```
79 71 89 57 76 64 82 82 67 80 81 65 73 79 79
60 58 83 74 68 78 80 78 81 76 65 70 76 58 82
59 73 72 79 87 63 74 90 69 35 83 76 61 66 71
51 57 81 57 65 81 78 77 81 81 73 75 66 56 62
75 60 74 74 70 71 56 74 63 72 81 54 72 91 92
```

I suppose it's something regarding the NA values but I can not figure it out

Comment: Do you have a `vector` as input

Comment: I suppose that's what I have after reading from that txt file

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved the problem by adding if(!is.na(x[i])) before the first if condition!
Here is the code in case someone faces the same issue:

```
exA2b = function(x){
  m=mean(x)
  s=sd(x)
  print(x)
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  {
    if(!is.na(x[i])){
    if(x[i]<=m-2*s|x[i]>=m+2*s)
    {
      x=x[-i]
    }
  }}
  print(x)
}
x=scan("test.txt")
exA2b(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are trying to do:

```
exA2B <- function(x){
  m=mean(x)
  s=sd(x)
  print(x)
  x[ifelse(x<=m-2*s|x>=m+2*s, FALSE, TRUE )]
 }
```

Your error is coming from the x = x[-i]. R does not like to remove from a dataset the current iteration you are on.

The solution I provide vectorizes your problem, so it runs faster and it will print out the old and the new.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Of course! The ifelse() will run faster that a for loop if you begin to introduce much larger datasets to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's because of the `NA`s. The problem is you're doing something `length(x)` times, but you're removing some elements of `x` in the way. So let's say you removed 3 elements along the way; Now in your last 3 iterations you'll have an `NA`.

This will do what you want:

```
exA2b = function(x){
  y = x
  m=mean(x)
  s=sd(x)
  print(x)
  x = x[!(x<=m-2*s | x>=m+2*s)]
  print(x)
}
exA2b(x)
```